# coverなのに画像の高さが無効化される

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

bootstrap4でサムネイルリストを作りましたが、そのCSSで`object-fit`に`cover`としたにも関わらず、画像の高さが`cover`になりません。どうすれば改善するのでしょうか?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="row">
        <a href="#" class="theme-color-text w-100">
          <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/500/animals" class="image">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="row">
        <a href="#" class="theme-color-text w-100">
          <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/50/animals" class="image">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.text {
  position: relative;
}

.text::before {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

object-fitは高さを揃えるスタイルではなくて、ボックスその縦横に合わせてコンテンツをどう表示するかというプロパティです。
高さを揃えるプロパティではないのでそのコンテンツ自体もしくは囲うボックスに対して縦横を指定してやる必要があります。

object-fit
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

> cover
>   置換コンテンツはアスペクト比を維持したまま、要素のコンテンツボックス全体を埋めるように拡大縮小されます。オブジェクトのアスペクト比がボックスのアスペクト比と合わない場合は、オブジェクトの方が合うように切り取られます。

例えばimageに対して高さを指定すればその高さに合わせて拡大縮小されます。

```
.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```